# How to change the id of deep nested elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have this recursive code that transverses the DOM and adds a prefix to the id for all input tags.

I would like to change this to a more elegant jQuery, but I'm not sure how to structure the selectors or if the selectors need to be recursive..

cheers,

```
 function set_inputs(obj, prefix){
  for (var s=0;s< obj.childNodes.length; s++){
    var node = obj.childNodes[s];
    if(node.tagName == "INPUT"){
      node.id= prefix +'_' + node.id;
      node.name= prefix +'_' + node.name;
    }
    else{
      set_inputs(node,prefix);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You said it traverses the dom, what is `obj` in your `set_inputs` function?

Comment: obj is a DOM object. The code grabs the obj's childNodes and drills in recursively by calling the function again, which grabs the childNodes until it finds a input tag. Once found, it changes the id.

Comment: alright just wanted to make sure :)

Comment: To pull the deep nested inputs, use jquery find() and loop though the found items 

       $(obj).find("input").each(function(){
         $(this).attr('id',prefix + "_" + $(this).attr('id'));
         $(this).attr('name',prefix + "_" + $(this).attr('name'));
       });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pull the deep nested inputs, use jquery find(). This solution is much simpler code than recursive javascript. I did leave out the steps verifying the existence of id and name attributes which should be done for production code.

```
$(obj).find("input").each(function(){
     $(this).attr('id',prefix + "_" + $(this).attr('id'));
     $(this).attr('name',prefix + "_" + $(this).attr('name'));
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

For the entire DOM.

It would be as simple as:

```
var prefix;
$("input").each(function(i,elem)
{
 $(elem).attr("id", prefix + "_" + $(elem).attr("id"));
});
```

You could change the selector : `$("input")` - which selects all the doms inputs, to any other [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to target different elements.

If you wanted it separately in a function then:

```
function() set_inputs(col, prefix) {
 col.each(function(i,elem)
 {
  $(elem).attr("id", prefix + "_" + $(elem).attr("id"));
 });
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
set_inputs($("input"), "abc");//prefix ALL the DOM's inputs with abc
set_inputs($("input.btn"), "abc");//prefix inputs with the css-class btn
```

Answer (score 1):

No particular need to use jQuery for this either.  It could be done in plain javascript without recursion using `getElementsByTagName()` like this:

```
function set_inputs(obj, prefix) {
    var nodes = obj.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].id) {
            nodes[i].id = prefix + '_' + nodes[i].id;
        }
        if (nodes[i].name) {
            nodes[i].name = prefix + '_' + nodes[i].name;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I added protection in the code that your code did not have in case input tags exist without an id or a name attribute so the code won't error out if it encounters that.  If you didn't want that protection, the code would be shorter like this:

```
function set_inputs(obj, prefix) {
    var nodes = obj.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
        nodes[i].id = prefix + '_' + nodes[i].id;
        nodes[i].name = prefix + '_' + nodes[i].name;
    }
}
```

You call this function by passing it two arguments, the DOM object that represents the top of the part of the DOM tree you want to search for `input` tags in and the prefix you want to add to the IDs.  If you do something like this: `set_inputs(document.body, "test")` it will search the entire document.  If you do something like this: `set_inputs(document.getElementById("top"), "test")`, it will only search a portion of the DOM tree (the part under the id=top element).  You can pass it any arbitrary DOM object and it will only search the nodes in that hierarchy.

Comment: Hmmm firefox says getElementsByTagName is not a function

Comment: @garyM - You must have mistyped something because element.getElementsByTagName() has been in Firefox from day 1.  You can read about it [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) or see a [test app work](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2ccvu/) in Firefox.

Comment: @garyM - what type of object are you trying it on?  It works perfectly fine on a div container object in Firefox in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2ccvu/) and should work on all types of DOM elements.

Comment: Sorry, need to sleep... The code you provided finds all the tags in the document, I'm only interested in a specific portion of the dom tree. The obj must be an arbitrary node.  

I'm using this code to create a tabbed form that uses a common div that is cloned and placed in each tab's div. Each set of inputs requires to have a unique name based on the tab's id to prevent parameter name aliasing. 

I got it working in regular javascript as a prototype, then moved it over to jQuery. I thought it would be easier learning one new programming language and api at a time.

Comment: @garyM - the `set_inputs()` function in this answer takes two arguments, a DOM object (the parent of the tree you want to search) and a prefix.  It will search only the parent of the tree you ask it to.  It does not search the entire document unless you pass it the document.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to suggest a small change

```
$('input').each(function(){
    this.id = prefix + this.id;
});
```